# SQL Replace last 2 chars if last 2 chars matches

Tags: mysql, regex, where-clause

I hope someone can help me. I have a column with 160.000 rows. A lot of those column values (permalinks) end with "-2" which is unneccesary so I want to remove them. But I can't get it to work.

I tried it with the following query:

```
UPDATE wp_pods_cars
SET permalink = Replace(permalink,'-2','')
WHERE RIGHT( 'permalink' , 2 ) = '-2';
```

This query seems to be valid but the RIGHT() seems to make troubles. Probably it can just be used for a SELECT and not in a WHERE-clause.

I was thinking about Regex, but I didn't get that to work either. I already fail in finding the right regular expression for my case.

Comment: You should remove quotes in your `RIGHT` call, because 'permalink' is a literal string, not your column reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have single quotes around the column name, so you are comparing a constant string in the `where` clause.  The version that comes closer to working is:

```
UPDATE wp_pods_cars
    SET permalink = Replace(permalink,'-2','')
    WHERE RIGHT(permalink, 2 ) = '-2';
```

However, I would write this as:

```
UPDATE wp_pods_cars
    SET permalink = LEFT(permalink, length(permalink) - 2) 
    WHERE permalink LIKE '%-2';
```

The `-2` might appear at other places in the string and you don't want to remove all occurrences.

Comment: instead of `-2` how would I choose my own ending? such as ending with `101`

Comment: @Eduards . . . You would either modify the `%-2` in the question or ask a new question if you are not clear on what needs to be done.

Comment: just have @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove quotes from column name as per comment by Oleg .This may be another solution with your criteria, the MySQL `SUBSTRING` function extracts portion of a string, `CHAR_LENGTH` function calculates the number of characters in the string & finally assign it to `permalink`.

```
 UPDATE wp_pods_cars
  SET permalink = SUBSTRING(permalink, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(permalink) - 2) 
 WHERE permalink LIKE '%-2';
```

**More About:**

[SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

[CHAR_LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)